# How to populate a related field on selection of a choice field in inline formset

Tags: jquery, django, eventtrigger, inline-formset

I am working on an inline formset where:

a. the user will be filling the header data first

b. next while in the inline section, user selects a choice field (a product name) and I want this action to trigger filling other field/s with a value from a related table (FK relationship). The related field/s will have information like the pricing items in the related field.

I want this to basically facilitate user acceptance (i.e. without having to click additional buttons).

I have tried a few examples from the web (like populating the price field using a query) but I am unable to capture the user selection of product from the drop down list. Tried JQuery but I am not really able to get around.

How do I achieve this?

**The above question was posted sometime back.**

I have since done a little progress beyond what was the situation at that point in time.

My present dilemma is as explained below (hoping for some kine of solution):

**1.** I am able to now dynamically add "class and "id" to each of the formset elements in order for me to access those while manipulating user inputs.

**2.** I am using `.on('focusout', ...)` to capture the user inputs (incl. the **selects**).

**3. I am calculating the item amount for each row like this:**

```
    matl_price=0   // Price field id: "id_tIndx14"
    matl_qnty = 0  // Quant field id: "id_tIndx16"
    item_amount=0  // Amount field id: "id_tIndx17"

    $(document).on("focusout", "#id_tIndx14", function() {
        matl_price = $('#id_tIndx14 input').val();
    });

    // THIS IS CALCULATES THE ITEM AMOUNT::
    $(document).on("focusout", "#id_tIndx16", function() {
        matl_qnty = $('#id_tIndx16 input').val();
    // Next calculate the amount (=Price * Quant)::

    item_amount = matl_price * matl_qnty

    // Appending the Amount field with the resultant "item_amount"
    $("#id_tIndx17").append(item_amount)

    });
```

However, the appended value is not update in the table field "Amount" as shown below:

[image]

As can be seen the amount (1600) lies outside the "**Amount**" Field.

**4.** I had kept the "Amount" field as "readonly". Later due the problem of the amount value falling outside the input field, I have since removed the attribute. But it made no difference to the final result (amount value still outside the field).

**5.** I am accessing the jQuery codes from an external *.js file (within the app path).

**May I request somebody out there to help me with this?**

Comment: Can you share some code that you have tried?

Comment: `$("[name=$'product']").on("change", function() {})` is how you would add an event handler to all your selects

Comment: @IainShelvington - If I use ".text" OR ".html" in place of ".append" the resultant value is in line of the "Amount" field but then again the value is rendered as a plain text and the field (text box) goes missing. I have also tried .val" but then there is no data displayed at all. How do I get the amount field value rendered inside the text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was eluding me for quite sometime. And the regret is that nowhere on the web I could find this solution (not even on jquery [site](https://api.jquery.com/)).

After a lot of permutations and combinations somehow I struck gold!! I am populating the **input** field this way:

```
$('#id_tIndx17 input').val(item_amount);
```

And the result:

[image]